# Save and restore Qt widgets on exact location on the screen

Tags: c++, qt

I've been trying to use the existing code to save and restore the labels and also in the future the Qt widgets at the exact position on the screen where the user placed it. The way I am trying to do this is by using using a `QPoint position` variable in the `Label` header file.

So far the save and restore code works perfectly. The only thing is that the imported label image saves on the top left screen. I can't seem to crack saving and restoring it where the user had placed it using the `QPoint position` variable.

**label.h**

```
#ifndef LABEL_H
#define LABEL_H

#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <QtGui>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QFileDialog>
#include <QBoxLayout>
#include <QVariant>
#include <QGraphicsItem>
#include <QPoint>

class Label : public QLabel
{
public:
    // Constructor
    Label();

    Label(QWidget* aParentWidget)
        : QLabel(aParentWidget)
        , m_nMouseClick_X_Coordinate(0)
        , m_nMouseClick_Y_Coordinate(0)
    {
        m_pParentWidget = aParentWidget;
    }

    ~Label();

    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* event);
    void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent* event);
    void mouseDoubleClickEvent(QMouseEvent* event);

    QPoint position;  // Exact location debugged on console

private:
    int  m_nMouseClick_X_Coordinate;
    int  m_nMouseClick_Y_Coordinate;
    QWidget* m_pParentWidget;
};

#endif // LABEL_H
```

**label.cpp**

```
#include "label.h"

//---------------------------------------
// Deconstructor
//---------------------------------------
Label::~Label()
{
}

void Label::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    // Move the coordinates on the main window
    m_nMouseClick_X_Coordinate = event->x();
    m_nMouseClick_Y_Coordinate = event->y();

    // Display coordinates in qDebug
    //position = event->pos();

    position = event->pos();
    //qDebug() << event->pos();
    qDebug() << position;
}

void Label::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    //-------------------------------------------------------------
    // Allow the user to drag the graphics on the Display
    //-------------------------------------------------------------
    move(event->globalX()-m_nMouseClick_X_Coordinate-m_pParentWidget->geometry().x(),
         event->globalY()-m_nMouseClick_Y_Coordinate-m_pParentWidget->geometry().y());
}

void Label::mouseDoubleClickEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    //QByteArray bArray;
    //QBuffer buffer(&bArray);
    //buffer.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);

    //--------------------------------
    // Open file dialog
    //--------------------------------
    QFileDialog dialog(this);
    dialog.setNameFilter(tr("Images(*.png, *.dxf, *.jpg"));
    dialog.setViewMode(QFileDialog::Detail);
    QString fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,
        tr("Open Images"),
        "/home",
        tr("Image Files (*.png *.jpg *.bmp)"));


    if (!fileName.isEmpty())
    {
        QImage image(fileName);
        Label::setPixmap(fileName);
        Label::adjustSize();
    }
}
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    readSettings();
    ui->setupUi(this);

    // Set up the window size
    this->setWindowTitle(QString::fromUtf8("Raspberry PI GUI v1.0"));

    this->resize(800, 400);

    // Add label Button
    button = new QPushButton("Add Graphic", this);
    button->setGeometry(QRect(QPoint(10, 20), QSize(200, 50)));
    button->show();
    QObject::connect(button, SIGNAL(pressed()), this, SLOT(input_label()));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::input_label()
{
    Label *label = new Label(this);
    label->setText("New Graphic");
    label->show();
    this->labels.append(label);
}

void MainWindow::writeSettings()
{
  // Save location
  //https://www.ics.com/designpatterns/book/qsettings.html

  int i = 1;
  Q_FOREACH(auto label, labels)
  {
    if (label->pixmap() != nullptr)
    {
      QByteArray bArray;
      QBuffer buffer(&bArray);
      buffer.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
      label->pixmap()->save(&buffer, "PNG");

      QSettings settings("Save state", "GUIApp");
      settings.beginGroup("MainWindow");
      settings.setValue(QString("image-%1").arg(i), bArray);

      ++i;
    }
  }
}

void MainWindow::readSettings()
{
    QSettings settings("Save state", "GUIApp");

    settings.beginGroup("MainWindow");
    int i = 1;
    while (true)
    {
      // Restore position
      // Need to find a way to find coordinates of x and y from label
      QPoint pos = settings.value("pos", QPoint(Label.position)).toPoint();

      QByteArray image = settings.value(QString("image-%1").arg(i)).toByteArray();
      if (!image.isNull()) {
        QPixmap pixmap;
        if (pixmap.loadFromData(image))
        {
          input_label(); // add new label
          this->labels.back()->setPixmap(pixmap);
        }
      } else break;
      ++i;
    }
}

void MainWindow::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event)
{
    writeSettings();
    event->accept();
}
```

Comment: What is exactly your problem? Are you being able to place it and move but you can't restore it after the application closes?

Comment: I am able to place it and move it but I can't restore it on the location where the user placed it on the screen.

Comment: Why do you not save the position of the label within its parent using `QWidget::pos`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to write down and read the position in order to add the restore functionality. Code below is just a draft of the idea, I haven't tested it, but hopefully will guide you to the final solution.

*Note:* I've also included some modifications in order to simplify your code, since you have redundant information which complicates the solution. To mention two:

- I've removed the `m_nMouseClick_X_Coordinate`, `m_nMouseClick_Y_Coordinate` and `position`, you can sue the built in `pos()` instead
- you can use [`QWidget::parentWidget`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#parentWidget) to access the parent

---

Modified `Label`:

```
class Label : public QLabel
{
public:    
    // Constructor
    Label();

    Label(QWidget* aParentWidget)
        : QLabel(aParentWidget)
    {
        // for this solution aParentWidget CANNOT be null
    }

    ~Label();

    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* event);
    void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent* event);
    void mouseDoubleClickEvent(QMouseEvent* event);
};
```

In the .cpp file (for shortness, removed obvious code)

```
void Label::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    move(parentWidget()->mapFromGlobal(event->globalPos()));
}

void Label::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    move(parentWidget()->mapFromGlobal(event->globalPos()));
}
```

---

In `void MainWindow::writeSettings()`:

```
settings.setValue(QString("image-%1-pos").arg(i), label->pos());
```

In `void MainWindow::readSettings()`:

```
this->labels.back()->setPixmap(pixmap);
this->labels.back()->move(settings.value(QString("image-%1-pos").arg(i), QPoint(0, 0)).toPoint()); // default position (0, 0)
```

Label's position will depend now on the parents position. If you want to make it completely global change respective lines to:

```
// write
settings.setValue(QString("image-%1-pos").arg(i), mapToGlobal(label->pos()));

// read
this->labels.back()->move(mapFromGlobal(settings.value(QString("image-%1-pos").arg(i)).toPoint()));
```

---

You may have a small flickering when restoring the labels, due to the fact that you show them and later they are moved. To fix it you can probably read the position first, and pass it as an argument to the function that creates the label. To make it compatible with your button, give it a default value to (0, 0).